# C# List comparison, contains keeps returning true

Tags: c#, .net, list

Language C#
Goal: Check my argument passed exists in a LIST that is complied during run.

Problem: I'm passing an argument that should return false as it's not in the list.

Background during test:

1. Using a step definition, I'm passing an Enum `(enumText)` and getting its description as a string, this will be used to compare against my "List".
2. The "List" I extract the "Text" from a bunch of WebElements and store that in a variable "listOptions".
3. My check keeps returning true. `listOptions.Contains(enumText)`

CODE:
**Local class variable**

```
private List<string> listOptions = new List<string>();
```

**Method that where my checks keep returning true:**

```
public void CheckCategoryFiltersAvailable(ShoeFilterRef shoeFilter)
{            
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(ShoeDropdownButton));
    string shoe = shoeFilter.GetDescription();

    if (ShoeList.Displayed  == false)
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(ShoeDropdownButton)).Click();
        listOptions = CaptureStoreText(ShoeCategoryAvailable);
    }


    listedOptions.Contains(shoe);
}
```

**Method to capture and store text into list:**

```
public List<string> CaptureStoreText(By byWebElement)
{
  //My code works. I just didn't write it here
  return listItems;
}
```

**Enum stored separately**

```
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace Tests.Enums.DataRefs
{
    public enum ShoeFilterRef
    {
        [Description("Nike X")] Nike,
    }
}
```

Through my step definitions when I pass a filter item that shouldn't exist, my code still passes when it should fail.

I've tried LINQ with lambda expressions, but maybe I did't use it correctly. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: `listedOptions.Contains(shoe);` returns true or false, you ignore the result - so how would you know if this works or not? Are you writing tests? Shouldnt you `Assert` the result of that `Contains` call?

Comment: Wow just one of those days, I was totally blank. Ofcourse, I was missing the Assertion. Thanks @Jamiec